# Dataweave: JSON -> HashMap

Tags: mule, dataweave

Is there a way to convert a JSON string to a HashMap object using Dataweave?
I know I can do this using the `JSON to Object` transformer, however, I'm unable to do do this using Dataweave. I'm running into complaints about not being able to coerce a :string to an :object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return a `(payload)` from weave. It will be a `HashMap`.

Comment: I resolved this just as I saw your answer. I had tried that numerous times to no avail. This time, however, I added metadata to the previous connector (Output: payload) and it worked fine. Could a lack of metadata be related to the root cause?

Comment: Also, does the parentheses around your payload term have any implicit meaning? I had simply used `payload`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without DataWeave too, like below -

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer
                            returnClass="java.util.HashMap" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm able to do that without issue. The reason why I was trying to use Dataweave was that it seems to be the direction Mulesoft is learning towards for data transformation.